# Django Filters 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating an page that allows the user to filter a dataset, hit search, and see the results update below. I am getting the following attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' and I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any help is appreciated

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django_filters.views import FilterView
import django_filters
from .models import Book, Lead, File, Pick
from .filters import PickFilter
from .forms import BookForm, LeadForm, FileForm, PickForm
from cms.ajax import (AjaxCreateView, AjaxDetailView, AjaxUpdateView, AjaxDeleteView, AjaxFilesUpload)
from cms.views import CoreListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def week(request):
    #orders = Pick.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    orders = Pick.objects.all()
    #orders = week.order_set.all()
    myFilter = PickFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders)
    orders = myFilter.qs
    context = {'week':week, 'orders':orders, 'myFilter':myFilter}
    return render(request, 'app/pick_list.html',context)
```

pick_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load cms_tags %}
{% block title %} {{ title }} · {{ block.super }} {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}    

<div style="font-size:24px">
  {{ title }}
</div>

<div style="font-size:14px; margin-bottom:15px">
  Click on the arrows on the right of each contestant and drag them up or down to reorder them based on how far you think they are going to go. 
</div>

<form method="get">
  {{ myFilter.form }}
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<ul>

<table class="table table-hover" id="table-ajax" style="background-color: white;">
  <thead  style="background-color: #de5246; color:white; border-bottom:white">
    <tr>
      {% comment %} <th></th> {% endcomment %}
      <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;"></th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:name' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:hometown' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:occupation' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:age' }}</th>
      <th>Progress</th>
      <th style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="order" data-url="{% url 'cms:reorder' model_name %}">
    {% include 'app/filter_list.html' %}
  </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

filter_list.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load cms_tags %}



{% for order in orders %}

<tr id="{{ order.id }}">
    <td><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/files/{{ order.photo }}" width="50"/></td>
    <td><a href="" title="Leads" style="text-decoration: none">{{ order.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ order.hometown }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.occupation }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.age }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ order.age }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm border-0 reorder" title="Reorder">
            <i class="fa fa-sort text-secondary"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% empty %}
<tr class="table-warning nosort">
    <td colspan="100%" class="text-center"><small class="text-muted">No {{ model_verbose_name_plural|lower }}</small>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr class="table-light table-sm nosort">
    <td colspan="100%"><small class="text-muted">Total rows: {{ orders.count }}</small></td>
</tr>
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-vKMx8UnXk60zUwyUnUPM3HbQo8QfmNx7+ltw8Pm5zLusl1XIfwcxo8DbWCqMGKaWeNxWA8yrx5v3SaVpMvR3CA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">  
  {% block extracss %}{% endblock %}
  <title>{% block title %}ccc{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>

<body style='background-color:#e7e7e7;'>
  {% include 'include/navbar.html' %}
  <div class='row' style='background-color: #e7e7e7;'>
    <div class='column' style='padding-left:35px;padding-top:22px ;float: left; width:17%;background-color: #f1f1f1;'> 
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:black" aria-current="page" href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/pick_icon.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"></i>  Picks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:black" aria-current="page" href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/forum_icon.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"></i>  Forum</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"  style="color:black" aria-current="page" href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/leader_icon.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"></i>  Leaderboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"  style="color:black" aria-current="page" href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/bingo_icon.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"></i>  Bingo </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='column' style='float: right; width:82%;background-color: #e7e7e7; padding:25px'>
      {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% include 'cms/modal/modal.html' %}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-VEd+nq25CkR676O+pLBnDW09R7VQX9Mdiij052gVCp5yVH3jGtH70Ho/UUv4mJDsEdTvqRCFZg0NKGiojGnUCw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'cms/js/ajax.js' %}"></script>
  {% block extrajs %}{% endblock extrajs %}
</body>
</html>
```

error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/picks/filter/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account',
 'cms',
 'app',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django_cleanup',
 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : <!doctype html>
   3 : <html lang="en">
   4 : <head>
   5 :   <meta charset="utf-8">
   6 :   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   7 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
   8 :     integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
   9 :     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
   10 :   


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\app\views.py", line 146, in week
    return render(request, 'app/pick_list.html',context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 698, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\cms\templatetags\cms_tags.py", line 60, in get_verbose_name
    obj._meta.get_field(field), 'verbose_name') else 'name'

Exception Type: AttributeError at /picks/filter/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Traceback error on views:

```
context 
{'myFilter': <app.filters.PickFilter object at 0x04CC9FB8>,
 'orders': <QuerySet [<Pick: Claire>, <Pick: Elizabeth>, <Pick: Cassidy>, <Pick: Eliza>, <Pick: Daria>, <Pick: Ency>, <Pick: Gabby>, <Pick: Genevieve>, <Pick: Hailey>, <Pick: Hunter>, <Pick: Hunter>]>}
myFilter    
<app.filters.PickFilter object at 0x04CC9FB8>
orders  
<QuerySet [<Pick: Claire>, <Pick: Elizabeth>, <Pick: Cassidy>, <Pick: Eliza>, <Pick: Daria>, <Pick: Ency>, <Pick: Gabby>, <Pick: Genevieve>, <Pick: Hailey>, <Pick: Hunter>, <Pick: Hunter>]>
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/picks/filter/'>
```

Comment: put the `base.html` file? this is where the error is coming from..

Comment: Whoops, just shared that in the post

Comment: Can you put the full stacktrace? It looks like your response is not a proper `HttpResponse`, which leads me to think it is not coming from the view you posted.

Comment: Also, which `render` method are you using? can you put the imports? If it is `from django.shortcuts import render` then you should be fine

Comment: Added the import that i'm using to the views.py snippet above. full trace isnow posted too

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: You're passing `week`, which is the name of the view function itself, in the context.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
In the stacktrace, it says `obj._meta.get_field(field), 'verbose_name')` i.e., `obj` is a `str`, so the in the line:

```
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:name' }}</th>
```

`object_list` is a `str`. Notice you are not setting anything named `object_list` in your context - so it is set as an empty string.

I think you should pass a sample order and use it instead of `object_list`

---

Original answer:

Based on the error you posted, the response from your view is not a `HttpResponse` but a `str` and that's the reason you are getting this error.

Another thing, I assume you want to render `pick_list.html` and not `filter_list.html` in the view. The fact that `filter_list.html` does not extend `base.html` says that you are not getting the error from this view but from another view.

Comment: You are correct - I switched the filter_list.html to pick_list.html and forgot to update it in the post... that error is as a result of using pick_list.html